# Levy walks / power law distributions using Unity / C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, power-law

I'm wanting to create some AIs with a Levy flight based random walk. I've currently got them moving with a completely random walk (random distance between a min and max value, and random waiting time between a min and max value). I'm aware that Levy flights draw both these blues from a power law distribution. I'm aware that I need to somehow get each step size from a power law distribution, but C# has only a Random function, which is taken from a uniform distribution. I have no idea how to get a value from a power law distribution in C#.  How can I do this?

I'm a programming novice, so please make your responses as close to Layman's as possible!

Comment: What did you try? Show us the code

Comment: I haven't tried the levy walk yet. I've just done a general random movement, which is different to what I am now attempting. I'm aware that I need to somehow get each step size from a power law distribution, but C# has only a Random function, which is taken from a uniform distribution. I have no idea how to get a value from a power law distribution.